# Resize TextView to wrap content using XML

Tags: android, textview

This question has been asked tonnes of times, but I didn't get any of the answers work from me.

How do i get the textview to resize itself to accommodate the text that is larger than single line(may be around 5 lines)? Please note that I am looking at solutions to work with XML ONLY.

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_comments_textview_comment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/comments_comment"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

Here are the attributes that i tried without any effect.

```
android:singleLine="false"
android:maxLines="5"
android:scrollHorizontally="false"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

Can someone let me know how to make textview grow in size, without specify a constant height?

My total XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="24dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_comments_imageview"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/item_comments_author"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.50"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:text="@string/comments_author"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/item_comments_comment_date"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.50"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="@string/comments_date"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_comments_textview_comment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/comments_comment"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want the textview with id "item_comments_textview_comment" to grow to accommodate the comment given by the user, to upto a maximum of 5 lines. Currently it only displays 1 line and cuts the rest of the text.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your comment textview (item_comments_textview_comment) is being limited by its parent LinearLayout height attribute.  Change that height value from `match_parent` to `wrap_content`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try using RelativeLayout for the design of the row elements. It can help you to designate position of each of the elements relative to components to manage your design.

Not only that it can also help in boosting the performance of your application. There is an analysis available on this and this one particularly inspects a design similar to yours. Check here: [Optimizing Layout Hierarchies](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html)